# Cannot resolve keyword 'distance_gte' into field. Choices are: Shop_category, address, distance, id, name, shop_location, user, user_id

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, geodjango, django-filters

I have two model shop and customer

### shop

```
class Shop(models.Model):
     address = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    Shop_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, ) 
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=70)
     distance = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
     shop_location = models.PointField(null=True, default=Point(28.49, 77.33))
```

### customer

```
class Customer(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_location = models.PointField(null=True, default=Point(28.49, 77.33))
```

I want to set the filter on the shop. The shop will show to the customer if the distance between shop and customer under the distance given by the shop.distance 
and my views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
  Shop_list = Shop.objects.filter(
    distance_gte=Distance('shop_location',    
    request.user.customer.customer_location)
)
```

I am getting the error Cannot resolve keyword 'distance_gte' into field. Choice  are: Shop_category, address, distance, id, name,  shop_location, user, user_id

Comment: Exactly what is the `distance` field doing in the `Shop`? This is the distance to *what*?

Comment: distance given by shop under which it's I'd show to customer

Comment: but that is not data specific to a `Shop`, nor is it data that should persist.

Comment: How I can do this? If I want to print all the shop to those customer which comes under the distance given by shop

Comment: I have more data in shop but I not think necessary to write I have written those which is necessary

Comment: what I mean is it makes no sense to store `distance` in a field, since it is different for each user/shop combination.

Comment: can you specify how you obtain the `Customer` object? So the related `Customer` for the given user?

Comment: I have put the relation in model  `user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and specify the user in view                                      `distance_gte=Distance('shop_location', request.user.customer.customer_location)` then the error is **Cannot resolve keyword 'distance_gte' into field. Choices are:  address, distance, id, name, order, product, shop_location, user, user_id**  
 @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double underscores for a lookup, so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

Shop_list = Shop.objects.filter(
    distance__gte=Distance(
        'shop_location',    
        request.user.customer.customer_location
    )
)
```

Comment: @alltypenews: You divide it by thousand, so `Distance(..)/1000`.

Comment: please help me with this [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422101/how-to-use-inlineformset-factory-when-multiple-foreign-key)  if you have any other suggestion then give me, please I request you